# What is the general category-theoretic strategy for proving two Hom-sets to be isomorphic?

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory

Suppose we need to prove $\text{Hom}_{\mathcal{C}}(A, B)\cong \text{Hom}_{\mathcal{C}}(C,D)$ in some category $\mathcal{C}$, given some universal properties of the objects involved. The natural strategy that comes in mind is to try to construct the diagram expressing $\text{Hom}_{\mathcal{C}}(A, B)\cong \text{Hom}_{\mathcal{C}}(C,D)$ from the diagrams expressing the universal properties of objects $A,B,C,D$ and other relations between them. So the question is, what is the standard way to express the equivalence of Hom-sets diagrammatically, and what are, if any, the standard strategies to prove the isomorphism? For instance, it appears that, given a pair of isomorphisms $i_{AC}:A\to C$ and $i_{BD}: B\to D$, the pair of diagrams [image] should do the job, but I am not sure whether these diagrams are necessary, or whether it is efficient to use them in such context.

A typical problem I want to be able to solve is the problem 2.14.3 in "Introduction to representation theory" by Etingof et al.:

**Problem 2.14.3**

> Let $V, W, U$ be finite-dimensional representations of a Lie aglebra $\mathfrak{g}$. Prove that $\text{Hom}_{\mathfrak{g}}(V \otimes W, U)$ is isomorphic to $\text{Hom}_{\mathfrak{g}}(V, U \otimes W^{*})$, where $\text{Hom}_{\mathfrak{g}}:=\text{Hom}_{U(\mathfrak{g})}$

where $U(\mathfrak{g})$ is the universal enveloping algebra of $\mathfrak{g}$.

In this particular case, I understand that this is a special case of tensor-hom adjunction + the fact that for finite-dimensional spaces, $\text{Hom}(V, W)\cong W \otimes V^*$. But without this knowledge I don't know how I would be able to solve the problem.

Comment: I don't know what is "the absolutely basic knowledge required to solve it", so, I don't know, maybe? The knowledge I have about tensor-hom adjunction and $W \otimes V^* \cong \text{Hom}(V, W)$ is related to __this specific problem__, while I am asking about general strategies for solving problems of this type.

Comment: To find eigenvectors of a rotation matrix defined through its rotation axis and angle, you can use your geometrical knowledge of the way rotation works in $\mathbb{R}^3$, and find all eigenvectors and eigenvalues without calculations. However, if you want to solve the general problem of finding eigenvectors of a matrix, you have to use the characteristic equation and solve some linear systems. The latter is a general method, the former is problem-specific.

Comment: Leveraging universal properties, adjunctions and equivalences is pretty general. Calculus of ends, if you wish